# TinyMCE Event JQuery DOM Traversal

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4.1.5 and I'm trying to do some Jquery in a change event. I can't seem to be able to do any traversal of the dom from within the event declaration. Is there some trick to this?

My editor declaration has a bunch of stuff in it but this is the event declaration:

```
setup: function (editor)
{
    editor.on("change", function(e)
    {
        console.log($(editor).parents("#testID").attr("id"));
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be able to target ANYTHING using JQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target the editors parent nodes using jquery you need to get the editors id.

HTML

```
<div id='testID'>
  <form>
    <textarea id="instance"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#instance",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on("change", function (e) {
            //id of editable text area
            var id = this.editorContainer.id;
            console.log($('#'+id).parents('#testID').attr('id'));
        });
    }
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/nevt665q/1/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much.